# Flutter FCM onBackgroundMessage does not work for nested non-static method calls

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, static, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `firebase_messaging 6.0.9` with `flutter 1.12.13`. In the repo's readme: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab- it says to declare the `onBackgroudMessage` callback as a static or top level method. Which I did, but it doesn't work when this callback invokes a non-static method. The following example demonstrates this with a singleton class:

```
class NotificationService {

  static NotificationService _instance;

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebase;

  static NotificationService get instance => _instance;

  NotificationService._internal() : this._firebase = FirebaseMessaging();

  factory NotificationService() {
    if (_instance == null) {
      _instance = NotificationService._internal();
      _instance._firebase.configure(
          onBackgroundMessage: NotificationService.staticHandler
      );
    }

    return _instance;
  }

  static Future<dynamic> staticHandler(Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print("Static Func >>> $msg"); // Successfully prints
    return NotificationService.instance.instanceFunc(msg); // Fails here, complaining that it's being invoked on null.
  }

  Future<dynamic> instanceFunc(Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
    print("Instance Func >>> $msg");
  }

  void myVarFunc() {
    print("This is my var func");
  }
}
```

in `main.dart`, the notification service factory constructor is called:

```
import 'package:myProject/services/notification/notification_service.dart';

run(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   final NotificationService _ns = NotificationService();
   NotificationService.instance.myVarFunc(); // Prints successfully.
   .......
   .......
   .......
}
```

The invocation of instanceFunc fails, saying it's being called on null. The following are the logs:

```
I/flutter ( 6935): Static Func >>> {data: {title: Title_is_here, message: Message_is_here}}
I/flutter ( 6935): Unable to handle incoming background message.
I/flutter ( 6935): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'instanceFunc' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6935): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6935): Tried calling: instanceFunc(_LinkedHashMap len:1)
```

I'm not really sure if this is right way to handle this scenario. Since I'm new to Dart and Flutter, my knowledge is pretty limited. I can't declare everything static and work, that's not good design IMO. I'm probably missing something here.

Comment: You have your factory constructor configured to initialize `_instance`, but in this code at least you are never calling it. As such, `NotificationService.instance` is going to be null, and calling `instanceFunc` on it is going to produce the error you are seeing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understood you correctly. The factory constructor is called from main.dart, which I haven't mentioned in the question. But if you see the logs below, the "staticFunc" gets invoked. Which means, firebase was configured. Which happens in the factory constructor. Which means, it does get invoked. But I'll update my question to add the calling of the factory constructor.

Comment: Regardless, `NotificationService.instance` is null, since that is what the error is telling you. How are you importing that file in `main.dart`?

Comment: Like this: `import 'package:myProject/services/notification/notification_service.dart';`
I'm also now calling `NotificationService.instance.myVarFunc();` from main.dart, which succeeds. I've updated the question with these changes.

Comment: I suspect the issue is something finnicky with Dart itself when it comes to the Dart type matcher. Try changing `staticFunc` to not be a static method and referencing it with `NotificationService.instance.(non)staticFunc` in the factory constructor. (You should be doing this anyway. Having static methods in your singleton class defeats the purpose of making it a singleton class.)

Comment: It should be static according to https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging. Which says `Define a TOP-LEVEL or STATIC function to handle background messages`. Otherwise the firebase callback for `onBackgroundMessage` is never invoked. I agree it's not the best way to have static methods inside singletons, but what are the alternatives?

Comment: I can't imagine why firebase_messaging mandates the method be static or top-level. A method reference is a method reference, regardless of whether it's top-level, static, or instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some reason of not getting callback on onBackgroundMessage:-

1. onBackgroundMessage didn't worked on iOS so you have to implement platform check

For example:-

```
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        printDebug("onMessage foreground: $message");
      },
      onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : _myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        printDebug("onLaunch Kill: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume Background: $message");
      },
    );
    static Future<dynamic> _myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onBackgroundMessage: $message");
    return Future<void>.value();
   }
```

2. And You have to make sure that your Notification payload didn't contain the notification key because if notification key is exist in payload then notification directly handled by your system. So you have to remove the notification key from payload to get callback on onBackgroundMessage.

**Note:- If you remove the notification key then notification didn't rendered in systems notification tray. For this you can you local notification.**